# PTIJ: why did only the Rosh write a commentary on Masechet Hashanah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I am curious why the only person who wrote a commentary on the Talmudic tractate Hashanah is the Rosh, Rabbi Asher ben Yechiel.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the rosh wrote a commentary on hashana because only the rosh could find the beginning of the mesechata to start writing.